# Get the next to last element from a string split using linq

Tags: c#, linq, split

I have a string (folderpath) and am splitting it by a character (\) which produces and array of substrings (individual folders).
How do I get the last but one folder from this, in one line LINQ query.

Basically convert below to a single line LINQ query.

```
var test = item.Split('\\');
var count = test.Length;
var folder = test[count - 2];
```

I am getting confused on how to fetch the count of the array and then specify count -2, in a single line.

Comment: Why does it need to be a LINQ query?  What you posted will work just fine.

Comment: I might inline `test.Length` into the last line and eliminate the `count` variable, but this code is just fine and I see no benefit to using LINQ.

Comment: If what you want to do is *getting the directory name of a file* then you can do `new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\subdir\a.exe").Directory.Name` which would return `subdir`

Comment: @L.B thats the answer I was typing up as you commented haha

Comment: @L.B post as an answer and I'll upvote yours

Comment: @L.B Would you know about the performance of spinning up a new instance of FileInfo over the 3 steps I have, over say 1000 folders ?

Comment: @Adi I haven't tested it. Say your's is 1 msec faster. Would it matter?

Comment: @L.B I am not arguing that my answer is superior. Was curious if you knew the performance of 3 operations v/s new FileInfo. But thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Adi My comment was not about which one is faster. If something is more readable (and would not fail for a case like `c:\a.exe`), would you write a less readable code which is only, for ex, 1 msec faster. It is your choice.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any benefit to using LINQ here, but here goes:

```
item.Split('\\').Reverse().Skip(1).First();
```

Due to the reversal, this will perform worse than your existing code.

Comment: I didn't see an advantage either but was curious.

Comment: Let this be a lesson. Just because a technology such as Linq is awesome and syntactically sweet, doesn't always mean we can benefit from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, LINQ doesn't have a method to do this, you could write your own extension method to do something similar but looking at the source code for `Last()` - which is the closest thing to what you are trying to achieve - it actually does something very similar to what you are doing:

```
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0) return list[count - 1];
```

So there is no magic going on behind the scenes, in my opinion, you should just keep the code that you already have as it is does what it needs to and it is clear and easy to understand rather than creating an unnecessary extension method or complicated LINQ query

Answer (score -1):

Let's go full thermonuclear with this answer just for fun. We can create a single line query using LINQ with performance that is comparable to your solution but we have to create a couple of extension methods first.

The problem with `Split` is that it returns a `string[]` and what we really need is an `IEnumerable<string>`. Yes, all `string[]` are `IEnumerabl<string>` but not all `IEnumerable<string>` are `string[]` - what we are really interested in is lazy evaluation and we are not going to get that with `Split`. So let's roll our own!

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAsEnumerable(this string source, char splitter)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in source)
        {
            if (c != splitter)
            {
                builder.Append(c);
            }
            else
            {
                if (builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return builder.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can go as crazy with this as you want. Add overloads to accept `char[]`, `string`, and `string[]` to split your string. Use your imagination.

Now this is a good first step but we need something that is going to allow us to take the last elements of an `IEnumerable`. [Interactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) provides a `TakeLast` extension method but we don't want no stinkin' dependencies so let's roll our own!

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        var queue = new Queue<T>(count);
        if (source == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (queue.Count == count)
            {
                queue.Dequeue();
            }
            queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
        foreach (var item in queue)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can take as many elements off the end as we want.

The above extension methods look great! I'm sure there are some optimizations that could be made and of course we need to keep an eye out for edge cases but this should be enough for us to get started.

Now we can use our extension methods and LINQ. Here we go:

```
var folder = item.SplitAsEnumerable('\\').TakeLast(2).FirstOrDefault();
```

There you go - you have selected the second to last substring with a runtime of O(n) which is comparable to your existing solution and a (potentially) better space complexity since the `Queue` we are using may be smaller than the array returned by `Split` (this will depend on the `count` passed to `TakeLast`).

Comment: Um a `string[]` is also a `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @maccettura True! Perhaps it would be better to say we need 'lazy evaluation'. `Split` is going to parse the entire string and eagerly load the `array`. You got me on a technicality.

Comment: Downvotes. I guess some people do not appreciate over-engine... ah, I mean value added engineering. Good that I did not implement a circular queue.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ wasn’t me